# How to Map Sub Domains created in Route 53 to application running in EC2 instance with different port

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, hosting, aws-application-load-balancer

I have springboot application with different ports hosted in ec2 instance
Domain in Route 53

Domain Name : mydomain.com

App A - 8081,
App B - 8085,
App c - 8088

Instance IP : 10.xx.xx.xx

domain :
test1.mydomain.com point to 10.xx.xx.xx:8081/landingpage &

test2.mydomain.com point to 10.xx.xx.xx:8085/landingpage &
test3.mydomain.com point to 10.xx.xx.xx:8088/landingpage

I have some idea in creating Load Balancer and Target Groups in beginner level.
Your views are always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Marcin, Route53 can't resolve port, this is a workaround. Assuming you already open two ports on your EC2 instance:

1. Create 2 target groups. One to port 8085, one to port 8088. Register your instance to those 2 target groups
2. Create application load balancer (ALB). Create 2 CNAME record with subdomain as your need, route both to your ALB DNS
3. Optional: Create a certificate for your domain (ACM), it should enable SSL on `*.example.com`, register the certificate to your HTTPS load balancer.
4. Create listening rule on port 443 of your ALB (80 if you don't use SSL), route depending on your host name, each host name will route to one target group.

Answer (score 0):

Route53 is DNS web service. It only resolves names to IP addresses, **not** ports nor URL paths. For that you need to either setup a load balancer for your instance, or using nginx on the instance to manage ports and url path redirections.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want in DNS using Route 53.  See [Can DNS point to specific port? - Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55123/can-dns-point-to-specific-port/55124#55124)  There are several ways to implement what you want:

#### Virtual hosts and reverse proxy

It is very common to run Apache on Nginx on your server on ports 80/443 for HTTP/HTTPS respectively. Both support virtual hosts where you point multiple domain names to the same server and the forward the requests to other ports. See [What is a "reverse proxy" in webmastering?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133209/what-is-a-reverse-proxy-in-webmastering)

#### Multiple load balancers

You could create multiple Amazon ELBs that forward requests to different ports. Then Route 53 could point each domain to its own load balancer.

#### Content delivery network (CDN)

Amazon's CDN is called [Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). It has sit between your site and your visitors and do the mapping that you want.